# SET tx_isolation versus SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL (notably 5.5), it seems that we have two different methods to set the transaction isolation level. I just would like to know if I am right in thinking that

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
```

does exactly the same as

```
SET tx_isolation = 'REPEATABLE-READ'
```

and that this is true for the other possible isolation levels as well.

**EDIT 1**

I have not been precise enough. @danihp's answer is correct given my question. But actually, I intended to ask about

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
```

versus

```
SET SESSION tx_isolation = 'REPEATABLE-READ'
```

(note the `SET SESSION` instead of `SET`).

Are they exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Server system variables:**

You can use `SET tx_isolation = 'REPEATABLE-READ'` to set default isolation level on **server system variables**. *"The MySQL server maintains many system variables that indicate how it is configured"* This variable sets the default transaction level.

**Current transaction:**

You can use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ` to change isolation level from default to new level on your **current transaction**.

**Notice:**

*"`transaction_isolation` was added in MySQL 5.7.20 as an alias for `tx_isolation`, which is now deprecated and is removed in MySQL 8.0. Applications should be adjusted to use `transaction_isolation` in preference to `tx_isolation`."*

**References**:

- [5.1.5 Server System Variables sysvar_tx_isolation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_isolation)
- [5.1.5 Server System Variables sysvar_transaction_isolation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_transaction_isolation)
- [13.3.6 SET TRANSACTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html)

**Edited**

You can use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_transaction) to "encapsulate" several statements as a single operation. When you [start a transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), just at this time, you can change isolation level for this new transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
/** change isolation level here with SET TRANSACTION statement 
to avoid default isolation level **/
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for not having been precise enough. Could you please give a short comment regarding the edited part? (Accepting your answer anyway).