# Unable to connect registry between wso2IS-5.6.0 and wso2AM-2.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure `wso2IS-5.6.0` with `wso2AM-2.5.0` to access policy

I am following this [link from the wso2 docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML).

In that documentation, I find the following step:

> 2) Share the registry of both WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity Server. For more information, see Sharing the registry space.

From that, I followed this [link from the wso2 docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+External+IDP+through+Identity+Server+for+SSO#ConfiguringExternalIDPthroughIdentityServerforSSO-Sharingtheregistryspace) and am receiving the following error:

> 

```
ERROR - TransactionManager Failed to start new registry transaction.
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionImpl.java:3050)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:127)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getTransactionIsolation(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:639)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:329)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:306)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.resourceExists(HandlerManager.java:3130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.resourceExists(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:260)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.resourceExists(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1233)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:645)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:376)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.setupMounts(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:293)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:535)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2019-01-25 20:11:45,088] ERROR - MountHandler Unable to test existence of resource
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to start new registry transaction.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:105)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:639)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:329)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:306)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.resourceExists(HandlerManager.java:3130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.resourceExists(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:260)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.resourceExists(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1233)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:645)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:376)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.setupMounts(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:293)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:535)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionImpl.java:3050)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:127)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getTransactionIsolation(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:89)
        ... 61 more
[2019-01-25 20:11:45,117] ERROR - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Unable to create fixed remote mounts.
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.delete(HandlerManager.java:2649)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.delete(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:215)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.delete(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:443)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.delete(EmbeddedRegistry.java:851)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.delete(CacheBackedRegistry.java:595)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.deleteInternal(UserRegistry.java:867)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1100(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:842)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:839)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.delete(UserRegistry.java:839)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.setupMounts(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:305)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:535)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.delete(MountHandler.java:490)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.del
```

What am I doing incorrectly when attempting to configure registry between `wso2is-5.6.0` and `wso2AM-2.5.0`?

Comment: MySQL v8? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47576028/1227152).

Comment: I am using MySQL 8.0.11

Comment: Then check that your JDBC driver is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Fixed spelling and grammar. Added error message to a block.